# Help understanding exactly the phases of stone tool development during the stone age?

Tags: technology, archaeology, prehistory

I have been studying how the stone tools evolved for the past few days, and think I am close to understanding *roughly* what the model is, but after reading a few recent papers, it seems there's a lot of stuff still in motion and not nailed down exactly, or else I am just misunderstanding. So I wanted to show you how I am thinking about it, and then get your help on what I'm getting wrong so it can be corrected.

I pieced together this rough list of "periods" in archaeology, from a few different Wikipedia pages like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_Paleolithic) one (they all said different things, sometimes conflicting or missing stuff).

- Africa

  - North Africa

    - Stone Age

      - Lower Paleolithic

        - Lomekwi (3.3 Ma)
        - Oldowan (2.6 - 1.7 Ma)
        - Acheulean (1.76 - 0.13 Ma)

          - Madrasian (1.5 Ma)
          - Soanian (500 - 130 ka)
          - Clactonian (424 - 400 ka)
          - Mugharan (400 - 220 ka)
      - Middle Paleolithic
      - Upper Paleolithic
    - Mesolithic
    - Neolithic c. 7500 BCE
    - Bronze Age
    - Iron Age
    - Roman

I am only focusing on North Africa (not the rest from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archaeological_periods)), so I know there were parallel/other development branches going on as well. But basically I am just trying to get a basic outline of one of the "happy paths", one of the main stories. I need to eventually go back and understand the other cultures like China and SouthEast Asia and others, but I think this question can be answered roughly without going into too much detail there for now.

I have a hard time with the periods, especially the names, so I went ahead and tried to list out the key developments, because my mind works better with timelines.

1. 3.4mya: **Pounded stone tools**: Origin of pounding rocks to make stone tools.
2. 2.6mya: **Flaked stone tools**: Origin of flaking rocks to make better stone tools.
3. 1.8mya: **Pear-shaped axes**: Origin of making pear-shaped hand axes.
4. 1.5mya: **Two-sided axes**: Origin of making axes and cleavers which were flaked on both sides.
5. 500kya: **Make tool-making tools**: Origin of making stone tools to aid in the making of other stone tools.
6. 420kya: **Bind tools to sticks**. Like for jabs and stuff?
7. 400kya: **Scrapers and blades**. Make the blades sharper like a knife.
8. 200kya: **Spears with sharp points**. Make points.
9. 65kya: **Bows and arrows**
10. 30kya: **Grinding stone tools**. Like mortar and pestal?

When I read about the first two and tried to compare them in the papers, like *[3.3-million-year-old stone tools from Lomekwi 3, West Turkana, Kenya](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277004244_33-million-year-old_stone_tools_from_Lomekwi_3_West_Turkana_Kenya)*, I couldn't really see a difference, so was scrounging to try and make a difference. Same with #3 and #4, they seemed the same, and for #5 I thought they already had "cores" to help shape tools, so maybe I'm wrong there as well. Then #6, it sounded similar to the previous ones, so I just picked out what I saw that might be difference when I think I read about "binding" rocks to sticks. Then #7 I can see a new development being *sharpness* of the blade, and for #8, a point which might not have existed. Then bows and arrows and grinding are totally new developments so those are easy.

But I'm stuck on the first 6 or so, how do they differ? What was actually introduced at each step? Don't necessarily need to go into every detail, but just a brief feature per item might be helpful to start, to show how they differed from the other items.